# Java byte array to ByteBuffer or ByteBuffer to byte array convertion "WITHOUT COPYING"

Tags: java, java-native-interface, nio

the biggest problem on java arrays , they require copying to edit.
I am using AMD Aparapi , which i get byte array from my calculations.
I need to show that byte array as a bytebuffer "without copying"

```
byte aparapiData[];
ByteBuffer buffer;
...
//here bytebuffer
buffer.clear();
buffer.put(aparapiData);
buffer.flip();

socket.write(buffer);
```

The problem here on code , buffer.put is copying byte array to bytebuffer.
And also there is reverse problem to convert byte array to bytebuffer.

Are they really require copying data?
I can send pure data on C++ without copying.

How can i solve this issue on Java ?

Comment: Why not `socket.write(aparapiData)`?

Comment: `byte aparapiData[]` should really be `byte[] aparapiData`; the fact that it's an array is part of the data type, not the name.

Comment: Java arrays do not 'require copying to edit'. And nobody is forcing you to use NIO channels. What's your actual problem?

Answer (score 53):

To get a ByteBuffer that points to an existing byte array, you can use the [`wrap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap-byte:A-) function:

```
byte[] array = /* something */;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
```

To get a byte array that points to an existing ByteBuffer, you can use the [`array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array--) method:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = /* something */;
byte[] array = buffer.array();
```

*However*, note that the latter only works when the ByteBuffer is backed by an array (i.e. if [`hasArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#hasArray--) returns `true`).

The reason for this lack of symmetry is that a ByteBuffer could be implemented in any number of different ways. Sometimes it is implemented as just an array in memory, but it's quite possible that it could read data from the disk or from the network or from some other source when queried. In this case, you can't just access the underlying array because there is none.